# How to convert objective-c snippet to Rubymotion

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion. I need to "convert" this Objective C code into ruby. How should it look like. I am stuck.

```
ASRemoteIndex *index = [apiClient getIndex:@"YourIndexName"];
[index search:[ASQuery queryWithFullTextQuery:@"jim"]
  success:^(ASRemoteIndex *index, ASQuery *query, NSDictionary *answer) {

} failure:nil];

// setting some query parameters
ASQuery* query = [ASQuery queryWithFullTextQuery:@"jim"];
query.hitsPerPage = 5;
[index search:query success:^(ASRemoteIndex *index, ASQuery *query, NSDictionary *answer) {

} failure:nil];
```

Comment: try some online converter, something like [this](http://objc2rubymotion.herokuapp.com/), may it help little bit.

Comment: I tried that but that gives not help

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
index.search(ASQuery.queryWithFullTextQuery("jim"), success:lambda do |index, query, answer|
       # optional block code here
    end, failure:nil)

query = ASQuery.queryWithFullTextQuery("jim")
index.search(query, success:lambda do |index, query, answer|
       # optional block code here
    end, failure:nil)
```

Read about it here: [RubyMotion Runtime Guide: Function Pointers and Blocks](http://www.rubymotion.com/developers/guides/manuals/cocoa/runtime/#_function_pointers_and_blocks)